# save users confirmed phone number from firebase ui auth phone number authentication system

Tags: javascript, firebase, callback, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

```js
/**
 * @return {!Object} The FirebaseUI config.
 */
function getUiConfig() {
  return {
    'callbacks': {
      // Called when the user has been successfully signed in.
    'signInSuccess': function(user, credential, redirectUrl) {
    // You can also access this via 
    //document.cookie = (firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumbe)
   //setCookie('phoneNumber', firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);
  


    handleSignedInUser(user);
    // Do not redirect.
    //'signInSuccessUrl': "http://localhost:8080/CurrentLocation.html",
    return true;
  }
    },
    // Opens IDP Providers sign-in flow in a popup.
    'signInSuccessUrl':  "http://localhost:1357/Carrier/homepage_latest.html",
    'signInFlow': 'popup',
    'signInOptions': [
      // The Provider you need for your app. We need the Phone Auth
      //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        recaptchaParameters: {
          type: 'image', // another option is 'audio'
          size: 'invisible', // other options are 'normal' or 'compact'
          badge: 'bottomleft' // 'bottomright' or 'inline' applies to invisible.
        }
      }
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    'tosUrl': 'https://www.google.com'
  };
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to save the user's phone number after they confirm it with a code that is texted to their number. I posted this question on github and a user mentioned that i can use a  `signInSuccesWithAuthResult callback. In the ui config, you can provide a signInSuccesWithAuthResult and save the phone number to cookie in the callback. You can access the phone number by doing authResult.user.phoneNumber.` The link to this github forum is https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/383#issuecomment-387167882 I'm confused on how to do this. I need to save the confirmed phone number and display it in a html5 file. Specially I need to display it as a marker label for a google maps API pin.

```html
var data = snapshot.val();
  var markerLabel = 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
    },
    map: map,
    label: markerLabel
  });
```

If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

From the html/js file you'd like to display the phone number, you should still be able to access the same firebase Auth instance via `firebase.auth()`. And from there, the phone number is available via `firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber` as long as the user is signed in on it.

Comment: Could you please edit my code to reflect your comment